# Some numbers in the application version are not taken into account

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

When I right click on my project, choose Codename One Settings and then basics, I can set the version for my app.

Last week I updated my app from 4.13 to 4.14 saved it, generated the apk (on CN1 servers) and eventually submitted the apk to Google which told me version 4.13 already existed. Indeed I open CN1 settings and the version was set back to 4.13. I struggled to set 4.14 but I could not. However 4.15 was accepted as 4.16 was.

Recently I updated my app to 4.20 and the 0 was stripped off by CN1 Settings window which made the App Store complain that 4.2 was < 4.16. This time I set the version number to 4.21 and the 1 remained!

So it is not very annoying although it forces me to wait for another build generation! I am using the latest plugin version under Eclipse 64 bits Linux.

Are there some protected version numbers that should not be used ?

Thanks,

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version numbers are converted to floating point values so version `4.20 == 4.2`. This allows us to align the versioning system across platforms in a more consistent way.

The `4.14` issue is a bug we'll fix in the next plugin update. You can workaround it by editing the version directly in the `codenameone_settings.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks @Shai for the workaround and the explanations!